# Django dumpdata CommandError: Unable to serialize database: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: django, dumpdata

When I run the following command to export my database in a JSON file :

```
python manage.py dumpdata > datadump.json
```

I have the following error message :

```
CommandError: Unable to serialize database: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'19 22:00:00'
```

I think that at a moment the command tries to convert a part of a datetime to an integer and fails, but I don't understand why such a thing appears.

Any help will be appreciate,

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some data inconsistently stored in the database.
You should check that column data to make sure.

For what I encountered, I had my date column saving data like '2020-01-07', but during another process of adding data, the data was added as '2020/04/03'. I was not aware, but it was successfully stored in the database. I thus got the same error as you, only that my error is  `b'2020/04/03'`.